# mvn azure-functions:deploy not working with docker

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-functions

I am able to deploy my azure function using `mvn azure-function:deploy` with `os` selected as `linux`.

But when I set the `os` as docker, with image on Azure Container Registry, there is no response from maven command. It neither throws an error nor does it deploy. **It does not deploy the docker image**

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                <resourceGroup>${resourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                <appServicePlanName>${appServicePlan}</appServicePlanName>
                <region>eastus</region>
                <runtime>
                    <os>docker</os>
                    <image>myappimages.azurecr.io/myapp:v0.0.5</image>
                    <serverId>SERVER_ID</serverId>
                    <registryUrl>myappimages.azurecr.io</registryUrl>
                </runtime>
                <appSettings>
                    <property>
                        <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                        <value>~3</value>
                    </property>
                </appSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-functions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I then set the password for `SERVER_ID` in my `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
     <server>
             <id>SERVER_ID</id>
                <username>myappimages</username>
                <password>xxxxxxxxxxxx</password>
      </server>
</servers>
</settings>
```

And finally when I deploy via `mvn azure-function:deploy`, this is the output:

```
[INFO] Updating target Function App myapp... 
[INFO] Set function worker runtime to java. [INFO] Successfully updated Function App myapp. 
[INFO] Skip deployment for docker app service [INFO]
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
[INFO] Total time:  49.065 s [INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-09T23:08:40+05:30 [INFO]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on what fixed it. Very likely upgrading to latest version looks like fixed it. I am able to deploy now via mvn.

```
    <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.15.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
```